# char& operator[] overload reference return? (linked list)

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading, memory-address, singly-linked-list

So, I've been getting this error when it comes to returning the proper type of variable. It says something to the effect of "initial value of non-const must be lvalue"

Can anyone help me revise my code to properly return the character at the given index? This is a singly linked list project BTW.

```
char& MyList::operator[](const int i)
{
    if (i > size())
        return 'z';
    Node* temp = head;
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {   
        if (a == i)
            return temp->value;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't bind an r-value to a non-const ref. 'z' is an rvalue.

Comment: Pay attention to what the compiler is telling you, and what line it's complaining about. The line it's complaining about doesn't make sense. Ask yourself what you want to happen if code reaches that line.

Comment: A linked list question with relevant code, +1!

Comment: Thank you very much benjamin! I can't even upvote other people's questions yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem line is:

```
return 'z';
```

`'z'` evaluates to a constant that cannot be used as the return value for a function that returns `char&`.

Quick fix:

```
char& MyList::operator[](const int i)
{
    static char z = 'z';

    if (i > size())
        return z;
    Node* temp = head;
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {   
        if (a == i)
            return temp->value;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to return 'z' in the case where the index is out of bounds, then you have to make an lvalue out of it first. This could be done by declaring a static const char inside the function with the value 'z', and return the name of that instead.

However, think about what you're trying to do - you're returning a modifiable reference to a static const char (so I'm not even sure it will compile) - but conceptually it makes no sense anyway.

You probably actually want to throw an exception or something similar in that case.